# Python social auth can't create a model that relates to user

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I have python social auth configured to create a user using steam Open ID. And I have a separate model, player, that is related in a one-to-one relationship with user that stores extra fields, one of which is the user's steamid.

I have extended the pipeline to include a function that creates a player and saves the steamid into one of its fields.

Everything goes well when it is a user that isn't already stored in the database. So in other words, the application creates the user and saves the field the first time I log in, but the second time I log in it throws this error:

Cannot assign "{Dictionary}": "User.player" must be a "Player" instance. Where Dictionary is the set of fields.

Here is my function:

```
def save_profile(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
if backend.name == 'steam':
    player = Player(user = user,
        ingamename = kwargs['uid'],
        avatar = kwargs['details']['player']['steamid'])
    player.save()
```

Comment: I should note that adding that breakpoint in my code, the program doesn't even call it the second time. Only in the first time I log in does the program actually reach that breakpoint. The second time it throws the error without even reaching the breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Solved My Own Problem:
The problem was that my model was the same as one of the keys in the keyword arguments, so it was incorrectly trying to save the 'player' dictionary into my model field. Changing 'player' to 'profile' solved the issue.